# Carry success message through redirect after blobstore upload?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I'm saving an image as a blob using the following, but I'm not sure how to carry a message through the final redirect to display to the user:

JSP file:

```
<%
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
String action = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/servletimg");
%>

<form method="POST" action="<%= action %>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ...
</form>
```

The target servlet:

```
public class ServletImg extends HttpServlet 
{   
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    {
         saveImg(...);

         req.setAttribute("msg", "worked ok!");

         resp.sendRedirect("/");    
    }
}
```

The final jsp page we get redirected back to:

```
if (request.getAttribute("msg") == null) {
    Log.e("Hey we're missing the expected attribute!!!");
}
```

It all works ok, my image gets saved etc, but I don't see the "msg" attribute when redirected back to the main jsp page. Is there a way to carry a message through, or do I have to append it as parameters in the redirect, like:

```
resp.sendRedirect("/?msg=it worked ok!");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **redirect** basically instructs the client to fire a *new* HTTP request to the server. The initial request (and response) will be garbaged, including all of the attributes set. So yes, you really need to pass a parameter along the redirect URL.

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?msg=" + URLEncoder.encode("worked ok!", "UTF-8"));
```

and then in JSP

```
<p>Message: ${param.msg}</p>
```

Alternatively, you can instead also just **forward** to the resource in question, i.e.

```
request.setAttribute("msg", "worked ok!");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and then in JSP (as a shorthand for the [ugly and discouraged *scriptlet*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) with `request.getAttribute("msg")`):

```
<p>Message: ${msg}</p>
```

With a forward, the initial request will still be available in the targeted resource.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah if I use the forward() method, then app engine complains about it: [HTTP ERROR 500 - Problem accessing /index.jsp. Reason: Expected a redirect, tried to write content instead.] I guess this is a requirement specific to the blobstore service. I can use the parameters in the url instead then. Thanks.

Comment: The URL was just an example. You need to use the webcontent-relative path of the *actual* page which is been displayed as if you're requesting `/` by webbrowser. I have no idea what page it is, so I just used an example. It can for instance be `/WEB-INF/index.jsp` or `/home.jsp` or whatever. It's at least the page which should display the message :)

Comment: Oh no, I mean if I use the forward() method, with a working url, app engine throws that HTTP 500 exception. I'm sure the url is valid. So I think I can't use forward(), but must use redirect().

Comment: Hmm, that must be another GAE restriction then. Sorry, I didn't knew that, I don't use GAE. Go ahead with the redirect along with a parameter then. URL encoding is necessary since for example the space is an invalid character in URL's. As an another alternative you can also store the message in session (`session.setAttribute("msg", "it works!")`) and access it the same way (`${msg}`), but this has impact when the enduser has multiple windows open in the same session.